# Uso superfluo del riflessivo

Tags: verbs, grammar, word-choice, difference, regional

Buongiorno,

Volevo chiedere, come faccio a capire se usare il riflessivo o meno in quei casi dove, perlomeno, sembra superfluo.

Per esempio,

"Lo mangio" o "me lo mangio"

"Lo prendo" o "me lo prendo"

Certe persone, dicono anche, al posto di "penso che...", "mi penso che...". Come spiegare, a queste persone, che, tale forma, probabilmente risultante dall'italianizzazione di qualche dialetto, è scorretta?

Comment: Non ho mai sentito dire a nessuno "mi penso che" - per curiosità, da quale parte d'Italia vengono le persone da cui hai sentito dire quest'espressione?

Answer (score 4):

Tecnicamente non è un riflessivo (diretto), anche perché quei “me” (o “mi” in “mi mangio un gelato”) sono dativi, non accusativi (“mangio a/per me un gelato”). Semmai si potrebbe considerare un riflessivo indiretto (vedi oltre).

Più propriamente, si tratta dell'uso cosiddetto *affettivo-intensivo* che si fa di alcuni verbi. Per fartene un'idea, un rapido punto di partenza può essere [questa risposta della Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/grammatica/grammatica_1691.html), in cui viene accostato ad altri concetti collegati: i verbi pronominali (“farcela”, “andarsene”), i verbi usati con [valore mediale](https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/verbi-riflessivi_%28Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano%29/) (“stancarsi”, “muoversi”; nel link ci interessano soprattutto le sezioni 2.2 e 2.4, rispettivamente sul riflessivo indiretto e su quello mediale) e soprattutto il [dativo etico](https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/dativo-etico_%28Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano%29/) (“che cosa mi combini?”). Nell'ultimo link, qui interessa particolarmente la sezione “3. Usi intensivi”.

Tornando ai tuoi esempi con “mangiare” e “prendere”, sono corrette entrambe le versioni. Quella con “me” descrive un maggior coinvolgimento del soggetto nell'azione. Potrei dire per esempio che “mangio rapidamente un tramezzino” (solo perché devo nutrirmi), ma dopo “mi prendo un buon caffè” (che conclude il pasto in bellezza).

Personalmente non ho mai sentito “mi penso”, e suona anche a me come una contaminazione dialettale, o forse una semplice improprietà di linguaggio (magari una confusione con “mi sembra”?).